# Union-Find operations on a tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, union-find

can someone please explain the answer in bold? How it's done?

Below is a sequence of four Union-Find operations (with weighted-union and full com-
pression) that led to the following up-tree. What were the last two operations?

Answer: Union(D,A), Union(B,C), **Union(D/A,B/C),Find(B/C).**

[image]

Comment: feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation is used because of the **sets**.

Let us apply the four operations:

`Union(D,A)` leads to following tree:

```
   D
  /
 A
```

`Union(B,C)` leads to following tree:

```
   B
  /
 C
```

Now `Union(D/A,B/C)` means that because **D and A belong to the same set**, it does not matter what the first argument is, it can be `D` or it can be `A`. Similarly because **B and C belong to the same set**, it does not matter what the second argument is, it can be `B` or it can be `C`, **the result will be the same**.

The result will be after third operation:

```
   D
  / \
 A   B
      \
       C
```

Now because compression is also allowed, the `Find(C)` operation would result in the tree:

```
   D
  /|\ 
 A B C
```

If the fourth operation is `Find(B)`, the tree would remain the same, because when we apply compression after a find operation, we make all the nodes encountered in the path upto the root immediate child of the root, but since we will not encounter `C`, we will not be able to make `C` immediate child of `D`, as it is in final tree.

**Correct Answer**

The correct sequence of four operations is:

```
Union(D,A), Union(B,C), Union(D/A,B/C),Find(C).
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks so much